# clang_complete dosen't give suggestions

Tags: c++, vim, clang, clang-complete

I was trying to set up plugin clang_complete for vim. I have cloned repository from [its page on github](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) to directory ~/.vim. Then I typed there `make install` and I had got :

```
vim clang_complete.vmb -c 'so %' -c 'q'
```

I have set path to libclang and other required variables in my .vimrc:

```
:set nu
syntax on
:set paste 
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
let g:clang_complete_auto = 1
let g:clang_complete_copen = 1
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang3.8.so.1'
filetype plugin indent on
```

Input of `vim --version` included `-python  +python3`.
Still vim doesn't complete expressions like:

```
 #include<String>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
       String s;
       s.      
       return 0;
}
```

What could be wrong?